# Unity Javascript help on Stop and resume function

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have the below code in Unity JS. What I need is when function Count1 is called, function CountTime stops and starts again. Similar with function Count2 and Count3. But when function Count4 is called, CountTime should stop and not resume again.

```
#pragma strict

import UnityEngine.UI;

private var textfield:Text;
private var textfield0:Text;
private var textfield1:Text;
private var textfield2:Text;
private var textfield3:Text;

var timer : float = 0;


function Start () {
    textfield = GameObject.Find("TimerMain").GetComponent(Text);
    textfield0 = GameObject.Find("Timer").GetComponent(Text);
    textfield1 = GameObject.Find("Timer1").GetComponent(Text);
    textfield2 = GameObject.Find("Timer2").GetComponent(Text);
    textfield3 = GameObject.Find("Timer3").GetComponent(Text);
}

function Update(){
    CountTime();
}

function CountTime()
{
        timer += Time.deltaTime*10;
        textfield.text = timer.ToString("0000");

}

function Count1(){
    textfield0.text = textfield.text;
}

function Count2(){
    textfield1.text = textfield.text;
}

function Count3(){
    textfield2.text = textfield.text;
}

function Count4(){
    textfield3.text = textfield.text;
}
```

Comment: You have presented us atomic functions, I assume that the real code is more complex? Secondly you should not pollute main namespace with many functions, have you thought about wrapping them in util library?

Comment: Perhaps the update function is called into a setTimeout or something like that? We can't do much with this code sir, including the fact that the unityUI is surely not the simpliest javascript library in the universe :P

Comment: @Beri. I do not have any other script yet. I have shown the complete script which I have done so far. I am not aware of wrapping in util library and what it does. the code runs a timer in Text UI "TimerMain". I have assigned the functions Count1, Count2, Count3 and Count4 to Button1, Button2, Button3 and Button4. The timer keeps ticking but does not stop even after 4th button is pressed. This is my concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give more details of your programs logic.
If you want to set timer 0 in button1-2-3 functions you can set `timer = 0f;`

Maybe you can add a flag your Count4 button event. And check it's value on Update.
I assume you want to reset timer Count1,Count2,Count3 methods.

```
var timer : float = 0;
var count4IsPressed = false;

function Start () {
    textfield = GameObject.Find("TimerMain").GetComponent(Text);
    textfield0 = GameObject.Find("Timer").GetComponent(Text);
    textfield1 = GameObject.Find("Timer1").GetComponent(Text);
    textfield2 = GameObject.Find("Timer2").GetComponent(Text);
    textfield3 = GameObject.Find("Timer3").GetComponent(Text);
}

function Update(){
    if(!count4IsPressed){
        CountTime();
    }  
}

function CountTime()
{
        timer += Time.deltaTime*10;
        textfield.text = timer.ToString("0000");

}

function Count1(){
    textfield0.text = textfield.text;
    timer = 0;
}

function Count2(){
    textfield1.text = textfield.text;
}

function Count3(){
    textfield2.text = textfield.text;
    timer = 0;
}

function Count4(){
    count4IsPressed = true;
    textfield3.text = textfield.text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just do a simple option like adding a boolean check to see if the time should be on or off? Then you could pause it whenever you need to or set it to `false` and never restart. Please excuse my syntax if it's wrong, I only work with c#.

```
var timer : float = 0;
var isCounting : boolean = true;

function Update(){
    if (isCounting)
    {
        CountTime();
    }
}

function Count1(){
    isCounting = false;
    // Do some stuff...
    textfield0.text = textfield.text;
    isCounting = false;
}

// Other methods/functions...

function Count4(){
    isCounting = false;
    textfield3.text = textfield.text;
}
```

Alternatively, if you are needing your time to go back to `0.0f` on these functions, simple insert the statement `timer = 0.0f;` wherever you'd like to restart the time.

Comment: Thanks @ Volearix. I was able to set the timer to 0 everytime. However, I am unable to stop the timer once button4 is clicked.

Comment: I changed the code to disable the textfield on fourth function and added the enable in Start() function. This is giving a near result.

Comment: @PrashantVaingankar Is it not the result you require? Not sure I understand your entire need if not.